# Terraform fmt fails with indentation error

Tags: vim, terraform, vi

I'm working on upgrading existing terraform resource from 0.11.3 to 0.12.0. I have a module directory and directories for state files(nonprod and prod), I ran terraform fmt command on a module to check my syntax, I'm suddenly getting this error,

error :

> Error running fmt: In file.tf: At 27:10: Unknown token:
>   27:10 IDENT merge

It worked in terraform 0.11.13 version.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "table-x" {
  name           = "table-A"
  read_capacity  = 100                  //autoscaling enabled
  write_capacity = 100                  //autoscaling enabled
  hash_key       = "Id"
  range_key      = "appId"

  attribute {
    name = "Id"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "appId"
    type = "S"
  }

  lifecycle {
    # Ignore the capacity changes to keep auto-scaling configuration
    prevent_destroy = true
    ignore_changes  = ["read_capacity", "write_capacity"]
  }

  tags = merge(local.global_tags,var.extra_tags)

}
```

variable:

```
variable "extra_tags" {
  type    = map
  default = {}
}
```

locals:

```
locals {
  global_tags = {
    email = "a-bp@x.com"
    owner = "x"
  }
}
```

But how should i pass the locals value for the tags?

Please let me know an alternative i can use, because the tags differ in prod and nonprod environment , for example i have 2 tags in nonprod and prod has 3.

```
nonprod:

tags {
 email:
 owner:
}

prod:

tags {
 email:
 owner: 
 application:
}
```

i tried passing as variable , got the same error var.extra_tag

`tags = var.extra_tags`

Update: I just passed it as variable in the module but even `merge(local.global_tags,var.extra_tags)` also works , unless i run terraform fmt in module, i don't have any issues, I was able to successfully do an import . But If anybody knows how to pass `merge` in tags for 12.0 version, please do post your answers, would definitely like to know how it works.

Comment: The `lifecycle` directive should be inside a `resource` block. Is that what you have (just didn't paste all of it) or what you have matches exactly what's in the question (no `resource` block)?

Comment: It's not the indent that's an issue, it's the `merge` keyword (`IDENT` is short for identity). Can you share the complete file instead of that snippet?

Comment: @filbranden The resource block is not necessary, dynamodb does not need separate resource block for lifecycle.

Comment: That error message you got from `terraform fmt` is a Terraform 0.11 message, suggesting that you tried to format Terraform 0.12 configuration with Terraform 0.11. Once you've upgraded your configuration to Terraform 0.12 syntax, you must use the `terraform fmt` command from Terraform 0.12.

Answer (score 1):

For the error

```
Terraformfmt............................................................Failed
```

I used `terraform fmt --recursive` command.